# How to copy data from one Tkinter Text widget to another?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Whois Tool")

text = Text()
text1 = Text()

text1.config(width=15, height=1)
text1.pack()

def button1():
    text.insert(END, text1)

b = Button(root, text="Enter", width=10, height=2, command=button1)
b.pack()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.config(width=60, height=15)
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I add the data from a text widget to another text widget?

For example, I'm trying to insert the data in `text1` to `text`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to insert a `Text` reference at the end of another `Text` widget (does not make much sense), but what you actually want to do is to copy the contents of a `Text` widget to another:

```
def button1():
    text.insert(INSERT, text1.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
```

Not an intuitive way to do it in my opinion. `"1.0"` means line `1`, column `0`.  Yes, the lines are 1-indexed and the columns are 0-indexed.

---

Note that you may not want to import the entire `Tkinter` package, using `from Tkinter import *`.  It will likely lead to confusion down the road.  I would recommend using:

```
import Tkinter
text = Tkinter.Text()
```

Another option is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
text = tk.Text()
```

You can choose a short name (like `"tk"`) of your choice. Regardless, you should stick to one import mechanism for the library.

Comment: I get an error: 

    text.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, text1.get("1.0", Tkinter.END))
NameError: global name 'Tkinter' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, I did the imports differently then you while testing.  I've fixed the answer, but the way you're doing it can lead to issues.

Comment: and text.get("1.0") only gets the first letter, like if i put "hello" and click the button it will only print out the first letter which is "h" :(

Comment: You should get in the habit of always using `"end-1c"` rather than `"end"` or `Tkinter.END` or `END` (depending on how you do it...). The reason is that Tkinter always adds a trailing newline. If you want to get exactly what the user entered you don't want that trailing newline.