# Placing text box widget onto the screen using python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to place the text box widget onto the screen

I am using the text box to display the output of my program. text box  has to be placed on the right side of the screen

my code

```
import Tkinter

main_window=Tkinter.Tk()
text_widget = tkinter.Text(main_window)
text_widget.insert(INSERT, "text  message will display here")
text_widget.pack(anchor = "w", padx = 50, pady = 50)

main_window.mainloop()
```

but my problem is text box is not visible on the screen. how to solve that problem?

thanks

Comment: Can you show more codes? The three line can not describe the error.

Comment: @zhangyangyu thanks for the reply,  I am a newbie to python, if I get a simple demonstration  on how the text box works then it will help alot . because I am learning python by simple examples.

Comment: The three seems good. So if we want to know the problem, we need to know more. Maybe the error doesn't lie in these lines.

Comment: @zhangyangyu there is no error in those codes, but still text box is not visible on the screen

Comment: Since these three lines look basically OK, the problem must be in others you haven't shown -- so remedy that.

Comment: Is this your _whole_ program?  You're missing the instantiation of the `Tk` class, and you're not calling `mainloop`.

Comment: Bryan is right. [This question should give you the basic view of a program doing what you want it to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258097/python-text-widget-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Raj: are you sure this code works? It looks like you misspelled Tkinter in the import as TKinter, and you're using "tkinter" in part of the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley my code is correct, I just misspelled when typing onto stackoverflow. But my code runs without error in my PC, but to my surprise, text box is not visible

Comment: @raj: there must be more to yhe problem that we don't know, because the code you posted works fine after I fix all the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported `Tkinter` but in your third line, you used `tkinter`.

You might want to change your fourth line to `text_widget.insert('insert',"text  message will display here")`

```
import Tkinter

main_window=Tkinter.Tk()
text_widget = Tkinter.Text(main_window)
text_widget.insert('insert',"text  message will display here")
text_widget.pack(anchor = "w", padx = 50, pady = 50)

main_window.mainloop()
```

The above code works fine without any problems in my PC.

Comment: Actually, he's importing `TKinter` (notice the capital "K"), then using `Tkinter` in another place, and `tkinter` in others.